# How to reorder Items after looping HttpRequests

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, task

I have the following problem (using C# in a Xamarin / Android app):

1. Every second the UI Thread calls a DoLongTaskAsync function which is awaited and returns a result item.
2. The duration of the DoLongTaskAsync function can differ, sometimes it lasts 2 seconds, sometimes just 0.5 seconds.
3. After 30 seconds I wanna put the result items in the same order like the calls that have been done.
4. I can not pass a variable to the DoLongTaskAsync.

I can't just put them in a list after the await of the DoLongTaskAsync, cause the duration can differ and result 2 may return before call 1 has finished.

I also can't store some timestamp before the await of the DoLongTaskAsync cause they will get overriden for each call from the UI thread.

Whats the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just `lock` your `List<T>` before adding the result, inside your DoLongTaskAsync function.

```
List<object> results = new List<object>();

private void DoLongTaskAsync()
{
   object result = null;
   /*
    Do HttpRequest, etc.
   */

   lock (results)
   {
        results.Add(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks. havent tried it out yet, but shouldn't be the http requestbinside the lock code?

Comment: If you do that, only one request will run at a time.

Comment: your code doesn't work unfortunately, cause i don't know thich result enters the "lock" statement first (i don't know what comes back first from the HttpRequest).

Comment: @TobiasvonFalkenhayn If you could update your question, and include a minimal code example, I (or someone else) could be of more help.

Comment: @TobiasvonFalkenhayn In response to your comment specifically, each thread will enter the `lock` block in the order which encountered, and only one thread will execute it at any give time. (ie. FIFO). System scheduling and timings may slightly effect the order of the results, but those variables are out of your control anyway given the situation as I currently understand it.